# How to make Firefox hotkeys to open an extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to open an extension on Firefox using a hotkeys. But how can I do that?

Comment: By "open an extension" do you mean "open the extension's `browser_action` popup"? Or, do you mean: register a shortcut key which my extension will be informed of when it's pressed? Please [edit] your question to clarify. Given your wording, I'm assuming the former (popup).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the commands API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/commands
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/commands

like this in manifest.json

```
"commands": {
  "my-shortcut-was-hit": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
    },
    "description": "Send a 'my-shortcut-was-hit' event to the background script"
  }
}
```

and in your background script:

```
browser.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  if (command == "my-shortcut-was-hit") {
    console.log("my shortcut was hit!");
  }
});
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/commands/onCommand

Comment: how I can edit manifest.json?

Comment: I thought you wanted to achieve doing some action when a shortcut is pressed. That is what the code above does - it's a Firefox extension in its own, that consists of a manifest.json file (partly above) - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/commands - and a background.js file, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background